Single Slit Diffraction Using White Light
So some days before i prepared a single slit using razor blade  and taken mobile flashlight as white light source and tried to do single slit diffraction with white light but what happens that i do see vertical dark and bright fringes but the bright fringes instead of being colored they were simply white. Can somebody please explain that what i did wrong  in the experiment and why i did not get colored fringes?

What are the details on the slit? That might affect things.

The slit is simply made of commonly used razor blades which were aligned very near to camera flashlight

What I mean by "details" is "how closely and at what angle were they aligned with the camera". Other very-important details would include the other lighting in the room, the brightness of the camera flashlight, etc. etc. etc. that weren't provided in the question.

The slit is aligned at 0 degree(aprox) with the flash light and the flash light used is a normal mobile torch (estimate intensity accordingly) and it was performed in almost a dark room.

photographs pls.
